# Retrieve last downtime for each region

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I wish to retrieve the lastdown time but I do not know how to do it.
In my script, I display 5 datapoints for each region and then I take the majority by returning the result. If item is equal to 200 then the status is up. But if item is not equal to 200 then the status is down and at this moment, I want to know the specific timestamp (datapoint). I want to put the value of the downtime into a file (temp.txt).

I don't know how i can retrieve the specific datapoint when the status is down... But for put value into a antoher file, i'm using fs.Writefile and fs.readfile

```
    var arr = [
      { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
      { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
      { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
    ]      

    for (const key in arr) {
      var region= arr[key].region
      var Value = arr[key].value 

        cw.getMetricStatistics(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        } else {    
        var status;
        //console.log(data.Datapoints);

        let downtime = data.Datapoints.slice(0,1).map(e=>e.Timestamp);
        let majority = data.Datapoints.slice(0,5).map(e=>e.Average);
        console.log(majority);    

        /*********** SCRIPT MAJORITY***************/

        console.log(item+" ( " +a+" times ) ") ;
        / Output 200 (up) or 400-500 (down)

        if(item === 200){
            status = "up"
            check_tab[key] = status;

            })

        }

        /****** NEED HELP IN THIS PART*********/
        else{
            status = "down"
            check_tab[key] = status;
            fs.writeFile('temp.txt',downtime, function(err, data){
                if (err) console.log(err);
                console.log("Successfully Written to File.");

        }    
        console.log("aaa: "+check_tab);

        }
        });
}
```

Actual results :

- Only 1 timestamp but this is wrong because it's a random timestamp

Expected results:

- 3 timestamp because 3 region and retrieve specific timestamp when status is down

Comment: I presume you are checking the availability of an application, rather than the "downtime of a region"? Have you considered using Amazon Route 53 health checks instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I would like to know the last downtime and not really the "availability".
No, i'm not using Amazon Route 53

Comment: The last downtime of _what?_ Your own system, or AWS itself? If it is AWS, there are multiple Availability Zones in each region. Can you be more specific?

Comment: In my script, I display 5 datapoints with timestamp and average. if the average is equal to 400 or 500, i only need to retrieve the timestamp. 
In my JSON, i have 3 element so i need to retrieve 3 timestamp ... For example status is down at 1547465578 (first element oj SON) and same thing for the other element

Comment: https://github.com/dojohnso/DowntimeMonitor/blob/master/index.php
This is a example of what i want

Comment: So you want to measure the downtime of _external websites_, not AWS? If so, what do you mean by "last downtime for each region"? What is mean by 'region' if you are measuring external websites? Or is the intention to measure your own web application running on AWS?

Comment: First: it sounds like you are reading from CloudWatch, with metrics CloudWatch, so it would be better if the question clearly indicated this rather than the seemingly irrelevant information about *"downtime... each region."*  Next: it sounds like you need to follow-up the call to `getMetricStatistics` with a call to `getMetricData` and then iterate through those results, if you want to find a specific data point... statistics are aggregates... but it isn't entirely clear what your exact objective is.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm reading from CloudWach with metrics. I don't know how to explain ... I'm display datapoints thanks to the metrics but sometimes the average is not equal to 200, so i just need the time when the average was nos equal to 200. For example (TImestamp: 14/01/2019 15:00; Average: 200) (TImestamp: 14/01/2019 16:00; Average: 400), So at this moment in my file temp.txt, i've got : 14/01/2019 16:00

Comment: the term "region" is not good for my issue... I have 3 element in my JSON is maybe more clearly ...